# How to create a directed networkx graph from a pandas adjacency matrix dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I have a pandas dataframe of the the following form, **df**,

```
    A    B    C    D
A   0   0.5   0.5  0 
B   1    0    0    0
C   0.8  0    0   0.2
D   0    0    1    0
```

I am trying to create a networkx graph from this. I have tried the following variations of code:

A)

```
G=networkx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
G=networkx.DiGraph(G)
```

B)

```
G=networkx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=networkx.DiGraph())
```

However, what ends up happening is that the graph object either:

(For option A) basically just takes one of the values among the two parallel edges between any two given nodes, and **deletes the other one**.

(For option B) takes one of the values among the two parallel edges between any two given nodes, **as the value for both edges**.

For example,

```
print( list ( filter ( lambda x: x[0]=='A' and x[1] == 'B', list(G.edges.data()) ) ) )
```

and

```
print( list ( filter ( lambda x: x[0]=='B' and x[1] == 'A', list(G.edges.data()) ) ) )
```

prints 1 and [] for option A.
prints two 1s for option B.

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: What line of code does this occur in? Also, what version of networkx are you using? I suspect that's happening because you are using a version prior to 2.0

Comment: OK, what line of code?

Comment: I have made an edit (although it doesn't have anything to do with your error), kindly have a look.

That error isn't popping up for me; it's working fine at my end.

Comment: I fixed it, but you'd better give us code (minimal example) we can copy-paste into our editor. This just speeds up the whole process

Comment: Seems to work pn pyhton 3.6 with `networkx` 2.1 -  In [132]: list(G.edges.data())
[('C', 'D', {'weight': 0.2}),
 ('C', 'A', {'weight': 0.8}),
 ('D', 'C', {'weight': 1.0}),
 ('A', 'C', {'weight': 0.5}),
 ('A', 'B', {'weight': 0.5}),
 ('B', 'A', {'weight': 1.0})]

Comment: ```G=networkx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=networkx.DiGraph())```  worked fine for me (networkx 2.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using numpy as a workaround.

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values, parallel_edges=True, 
                         create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())

# Because we use numpy, labels need to be reset
label_mapping = {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D"}
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, label_mapping)

G.edges(data=True)

OutMultiEdgeDataView([('A', 'B', {'weight': 0.5}), 
                      ('A', 'C', {'weight': 0.5}), 
                      ('B', 'A', {'weight': 1.0}), 
                      ('C', 'A', {'weight': 0.8}), 
                      ('C', 'D', {'weight': 0.2}), 
                      ('D', 'C', {'weight': 1.0})])
```

In a more general case, to get `label_mapping` you can use

```
label_mapping = {idx: val for idx, val in enumerate(df.columns)}
```

This seems to be a bug in `networkx 2.0`. They will fix it in 2.1. See this [issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2828#issuecomment-358157844) for more information.