# How to create a DiGraph from a csv adjacency matrix dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, networkx

I'm trying to create a DiGraph from a csv file with adjacency matrix dataframe:

```
Gdf = pd.read_csv("outputtest.csv", index_col = 0) #load the csv to pandas dataframe
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(Gdf, create_using = nx.DiGraph()) #turn the dataframe into Digraph
```

however it comes out a Graph not a DiGraph

```
[in]:  print(nx.info(G))
[out]:Name:
       Type: Graph
       ...
```

please help me to fix it

This is my first time trying to use Python, I have no experience on any types of coding, and my English is quite poor.

I've already try to search it on internet and find a similar question as mine:
[How to create a directed networkx graph from a pandas adjacency matrix dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235215/how-to-create-a-directed-networkx-graph-from-a-pandas-adjacency-matrix-dataframe?rq=1)

but the answer is using numpy and have to reset labels, which might not really suitable for my case that with much more nodes than 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in Oct 2017 (https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/2693)
Please upgrade to NetworkX 2.1 or the github latest version to get the fixed code.
:)
from    Dan Schult